# Large SELECT queries seem to return a different order to identical but smaller SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am performing an SQLite query to get all the image paths for a bunch of image ids. The order the ids are in needs to be maintained. If I query 5 ids, 5 paths are returned in the correct order. However if I keep the query the exact same but query 72,000 ids, the order I receive back is different?

Why is this happening? I've copy and pasted the 2 queries and the 2 results (obviously minus the full 72,000 ids and results).

Does this make sense to anyone?

**Query (With 5 IDs)**

```
SELECT Path FROM Images WHERE MicrosoftId IN ('78003','78010','78080','78149','78196')
```

**Result (This is correct!)**

```
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_082235_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_082904_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_092336_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_101818_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_105621_000.jpg"
```

**Query (With 72,000 IDs)**

```
SELECT Path FROM Images WHERE MicrosoftId IN (('78003','78010','78080','78149','78196','78229','78231','78236','78237','78238','78248','78250'...etc 72,000 more)
```

**Result (This is incorrect! Why did the order change?)**

```
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_050623_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_050710_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_050844_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_050449_000.jpg"
"~/ImagesPath/36/20160818_050757_000.jpg"
etc... to 72,000
```

**EDIT: How would you do a JOIN on these two queries?**

```
SELECT MicrosoftId FROM TagsMSCV WHERE name IN ('" + some vars + "') GROUP BY MicrosoftId ORDER BY COUNT(MicrosoftId) DESC
```

and

```
SELECT Path FROM Images WHERE MicrosoftId IN ('" + results from above query + "')
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause on your query. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: The ORDER BY is in the query previous to this. It has to do with the way the guy set up the tables in the database. I have to do everything with the IDs, then once I have them, I need to use them to get the paths I need. But the order I get the IDs is important; I need to maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Path FROM Images i
JOIN TagsMSCV t ON i.MicrosoftId = t.MicrosoftId
WHERE t.name IN ('" + some vars + "') GROUP BY t.MicrosoftId ORDER BY
COUNT(t.MicrosoftId) DESC
```

This join should do the trick

Comment: That literally turned a wall of code into a single line of code. I really need to up my SQL game. Thank you. Now to figure out how this all works, lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly specify an `order by` clause, there's no guarantee on the order the rows will be returned in. The database is free to return them in whatever order would be most efficient. Even if you do happen to get the result in the order you want, you can't count on it - any number of circumstances (e.g., rebuilding indexes, or just a row that happened to be on some cache) may change the order the next time you run the quetry.

TL;DR, if you care about the order of rows, you should add an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   Path 
FROM     Images
WHERE    MicrosoftId IN ('78003','78010','78080','78149','78196', /* etc ...*/)
ORDER BY MicrosoftId
```

Comment: The order I need is the order the query is in. I have to source the IDs in a different table, then I come to this table to get their corresponding paths. Is the only way to achieve this to marry the two separate SQL statements?

Comment: joining is probably the best way to go - it should both simplify your code and probably make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to organize your query into a `JOIN`:

```
select * from
    (
        select 78003 as mid
        union select 78010
        union select 78080
        union select 78149
        union select 78196
        # and so on...
    ) mids
    inner join Images on (Images.MicrosoftId = mids.mid);
```

That way, the query *should* use the ordering of the constructed `mids` table.

If you want to be extra sure about the ordering, you could tack on an ordering column to your constructed table:

```
select * from
    (
        select 78003 as mid, 1 as midOrder
        union select 78010, 2
        union select 78080, 3
        union select 78149, 4
        union select 78196, 5
        # and so on...
    ) mids
    inner join Images on (Images.MicrosoftId = mids.mid)
    order by midOrder
```